# Getting simple product in observer when adding configurable product to cart?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Magento 2.4.6

I am trying to get the simple product of a configurable product when a product is added to the cart. I am listening to the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. This is what I have so far:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
$item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
$logger->info('item: ' . $item->getName());
```

This however, always gives me the name of the configurable, not the child simple products name. No matter what I try to access, its always the data from the parent configurable. Any ideas whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- To access the child simple product's data, you need to make use of
  the **getOptionByCode** method.
- By using the **getConfigurableOptions** method, you can retrieve the
  selected options for the configurable product.
- Assuming there's only one configurable attribute, the first option's
  value will represent the child product's ID. You can then load the
  child product using **getUsedProductById** and access its name using
  **$childProduct->getName()**.
- This approach should give you the name of the child simple product
  instead of the parent configurable product.

Here is the example code,

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
$item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);

// Get the selected options for the configurable product
$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($item->getProduct());

// Get the first option (assuming there's only one configurable attribute)
$selectedOption = reset($options);

// Get the child product's ID
$childProductId = $selectedOption['value'];

// Load the child product
$childProduct = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductById($childProductId);

// Access the child product's name
$childProductName = $childProduct->getName();

$logger->info('Child Product Name: ' . $childProductName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
if ($item->getHasChildren() ) {
    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child)  $logger->info('item: ' . $child->getName());
}
```